# Add required Checkbox for Newsletter subscription form

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, form-validation, gdpr

Is there a way to add a required checkbox to the newsletter subscription form?
The idea is to make the user agree to the privacy policy before subscribing for the Newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you like using popup. If you can try this module: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-better-popup/ . It has a template and you can also customize everything with HTML. They also have a service to help you do that.